# Remote access Zero to JupyterHub over Ethernet with ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, jupyterhub

**Context**

I installed *Kubernetes* on a bare-metal server (4 nodes) and deployed *Zero to JupyterHub* to it.
This works fine; I can correctly access the hub from the master-node.

Now I want to access the Hub on the server from an external computer via Ethernet. Therefore, I followed the [official instructions](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/administrator/advanced.html) and installed [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) in order to provide an external IP for my *proxy-public*-service (which correctly sets).
Additionally, I installed the [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) in order to be able to do an ingress, which also successfully gets an external IP (little hint: Use the *Helm*-chart; I couldn't get the service running when applying the other recommended steps).

Since I had a little trouble figuring out how to do this ingress, here is an example:

```sh
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml --namespace jhub

#ingress.yaml:
#apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
#kind: Ingress
#metadata:
#  name: jupyterhub-ingress
#  annotations:
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
#spec:
#  rules:
#  - host: jupyterhub.cluster
#    http:
#      paths:
#      - path: /
#        backend:
#          serviceName: proxy-public
#          servicePort: 80
```

Anyhow, I cannot open the external IP *proxy-public* provides (meaning I'm inserting the external IP in my browser).

**Question**

How can I remotely access my JupyterHub over the external IP; what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed that this can be achieved in the same way as with the *Kubernetes-Dashboard*: You have to establish an open ssh-connection (hence, open a tunnel -> *tunneling*) from the external computer.
Of course this is not the "exernal" access I had in mind, but a working and fast solution for my test-environment (and maybe yours).

**How to establish this ssh-connect**

First, get the external IP-address of your *proxy-public*:

```sh
$: kubectl get services --namespace jhub
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
hub            ClusterIP      10.99.241.72     <none>          8081/TCP                     95m
proxy-api      ClusterIP      10.107.175.27    <none>          8001/TCP                     95m
proxy-public   LoadBalancer   10.102.171.162   192.168.1.240   80:31976/TCP,443:32568/TCP   95m
```

**Note**: The range of the external IP was defined in my `layer2` in my *MetalLB*-config.

Using this information (and assuming you're on Linux), open a terminal and use the following command:

```sh
$ ssh pi@10.10.10.2 -L 8000:192.168.1.240:80
# -L opens a localhost-connection
# pi@10.10.10.2 logs me into my second node with user pi
```

**Note1**: That `localhost:8000` is configured as targetPort for *proxy-public* with *http* can also be seen when you describe the service and take a look at the specs respectively ports (you can also get the settings for https there):

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: proxy-public
  namespace: jhub
  ...
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 31976
    - name: https
...
```

Finally, type `http://localhost:8000/` into your browser - et voila, you get to your JupyterHub login-page!

Comment: If you want to have remote access why you are using localhost ? Localhost is the de-facto standard (DNS) name for the local loop back address 127.0.0.1, which can not be accessed from outside of the (local) host itself.

Comment: Do you mean _port_ and target_port in the `proxy-public`-service description? To be honest, these are the standard-settings coming with deploying the official hub which I didn't change.. Should I just change _port_ and _target_-port? If you mean the localhost-ssh: This just tunnels onto the nodes localhost where `192.168.1.240:80` can be accessed.